# Query COUNT statement with multiple clauses doesn't work

Tags: count, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 3 columns like A,B,C and I'd like to count cells in column A which contains something (if is not empty) only if column B or column C contains a name.

I use this statement

```
=QUERY(Foglio1!A:V;"SELECT COUNT(R) WHERE R <>'' AND M CONTAINS "Alex" OR V CONTAINS "Mary"")
```

The problem is that it returns me how many times "Alex" and "Mary" appears into column B and C even if R is empty.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add some priority to both of the contains with some brackets.

```
=QUERY(Foglio1!A:V;"SELECT COUNT(R) WHERE R <>'' AND (M CONTAINS 'Alex' OR V CONTAINS 'Mary')")
```

Your original left the `V CONTAINS 'Mary'` hanging so that it could be interpreted as `(R <>'' AND M CONTAINS 'Alex') OR V CONTAINS 'Mary'`.